# Text Search with Meteor Mongo 2.6.7 displays "text search not enabled"

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have Mongo version 2.6.7 (I checked using db.version()), and I do a text search that works as expected on the local server. However, when I deploy to a live meteor site, I receive an error in the logs that reads "MongoError: text search not enabled". I'm not sure why this is since this is supposed to come installed

Answer (score 1):

.meteor runs an older version of MongoDB (2.4.10?), where 'text search' isn't enabled by default.

For more info, check this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5128

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today.
It's working on local server but when deployed to meteor it says

> [Mon Sep 07 2015 16:07:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)] WARNING MongoError: text
>   search not enabled

Any info regarding this?

Comment: Nope. I had to move on.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the meteor.com has old version of mongodb which doesn't support text search.